# Security Concern about uploading Parse.File

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any methods to prevent web client from filling my parse cloud storage with dummy files? As far i can see, the creation of Parse.File (without object reference) requires only valid api key which is plain text in client side. Does this imply that any others can impersonate to be my valid js client with the api key or did i miss out anything in the api reference?

Comment: No, that would seem to be a real risk

Comment: Indeed Wain, wondering how those used the service survive out there?